# Battery getting drain on iOS 8.1.2 ( Specially when keep receiving APNS only)

Tags: ios, objective-c, battery-saver

I am currently facing one issue about battery drain. My application is just seating in background. it is also not available in list of background app refresh. But when I visit Usage section it show "Background activity" 
Ref :

[image]

can I get information what this background activity means here. also when application is not receiving APNS battery drain is around 10%. but when APNS is received this is 34% battery usage. is there anything apart from background refresh which can cause battery drain. there is no any location update service running for my app.

Comment: The usage is going to add up to 100%. If the other apps have had little usage and you have used your app more, even a little bit but more it will ave a higher %. I just looked and say that on my iPhone Reminders is 74% just because I used it yesterday more than any other app even though I used it only a few short times.

Comment: Right, but it is draining battery though there is no any Upfront activity. I have only launched the app and kept application in background.There are other application running which I have used more than mine application. but after 24 hrs My application tops in battery usage.( This is more high in case of APNS )